# WKWebview navigation response method isn't getting called upon clicking done button in a webview

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I'm using `WKWebview` for my Swift app. For some reason, `WKWebview` navigation response delegate method isn't getting called when the user clicks the done button in a `WKWebView`. When I try the same action on the web, it redirects to the correct url.

So far I have tried clearing `WKWebview` cache before configuring `WKWebView` in `viewDidLoad` or if I get a memory warning. Also, ensured my `info.plist` allows arbitrary loads and `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` for testing purposes. Despite trying these things to debug, the navigation response delegate method still didn't get called.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        if let webviewUrl = webView.url {
            let urlString = webviewUrl.absoluteString
            if urlString.contains("\(myUrlComponents)") {
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                return
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

I want to be able to detect a specific `WKWebview` url when the navigation response method gets called and go back to the previous screen.

Comment: What “done button”? Navigation involves a link, not a button.

Comment: I know that. There's a done button in my webview. Upon pressing the done button, the page redirects to a different url. Normally navigation response gets called when that happens and I'm able to check for the new url. However, the problem is that the navigation response isn't getting called when the page redirects to the new url.

Comment: Are you sure it’s redirecting to a new page? As opposed to rewriting the contents of the current page with JavaScript?

Comment: “Upon pressing the done button, the page redirects to a different url.“ How?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg I'm not too familiar with web. I will ask a web developer whether latter is the case.

Comment: @mir Did you figureout a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that it will be called if you use the delegate function that looks identical to the one you're using except that the "decisionHandler" is a function taking WKNavigationActionPolicy as its argument.